# Dropbox shared folder view username of last edit

Tags: dropbox

I have a shared Dropbox folder with my team but I'd like to know who edited each file in the folder.

For example, let's say we have two users A & B. First A edits a file and then B does some more work on it. Does Dropbox provide a method of viewing that the last user who edited that particular file is user B and not user A?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox Provides a simple version control system which allows you to revert back and forth multiple edits.

More on [DropBox PackRat](https://www.dropbox.com/help/113/en)

and 
[Document Conflict Management](https://www.dropbox.com/help/36/en)

Comment: This is not what I asked. I asked that I want to know if dropbox can show me username of the one who did the last edit in a shared folder not versioning capability of the file.